# fixing button size in Menu

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to create CSS menu it's work fine but i got littel problem that when mouse is over, also in border , not covering all menu, it dosn't get to the bottom, this's image to explain more [image]

```
     <nav id="main-nav" class="grid_12 main-nav">

            <ul>
                <li><img src="style/menu.png" /></li>
                <li><a href="http://webdesignerwall.com">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://themify.me">Themify</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://icondock.com">IconDock</a> </li>
                <li><a href="http://ndesign-studio.com">N.Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

**Css File

   #main-nav { background: #51b2cc; margin-bottom: 60px ; margin-top: 10px; z-index: 100;
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #429db6;
         -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 0px 0px #429db6;
         box-shadow:         0px 3px 0px 0px #429db6;}

    #main-nav ul { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    #main-nav li {display:inline-block;margin: 0;border-right: 2px #5dc9e6 solid;list-style: none;float: left;position: relative;}
    #main-nav a {line-height: 100%;font-weight: bold;color: #fff;display: block;padding: 14px 15px;text-decoration: none;}
    #main-nav img {line-height: 100%;font-weight: bold;color: #fff;display: block;padding: 14px 15px; background: #429db6;}
    #main-nav a:hover {color: #fff;background: #429db6;}
```

Comment: provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your problem

Comment: this's fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/T4mVe/

Comment: how is you modify the `padding: 14px 15px;` to `padding: 16px 15px;`?

Comment: It work's , I Have missed this, I have to pay more attention

Answer (score 1):

Your image is taller than the line-height of your text.

You need to adjust the padding on the `img` so that it will match up to the height of the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/T4mVe/1/

```
#main-nav img { [ ... ] padding: 12px 15px; [ ... ] }
```